# Plausibility of a creature made of ice or other low melting point materials

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design

When I was younger I came up with a creature that seemed to contradict itself. It was made of some frozen material, but it had a large back fin in order to get warmth from the sun. I'm revisiting the idea, and wondering if such a creature would actually work, and what it might be made of.

If it can't be ice then what about a material that melts at a lower temperature? What's one that would melt at the temperature and pressure that we're used to and could work for life?

The planet it lives on has ammonia oceans, chlorine atmosphere, lower temperature than Earth's, and high enough atmospheric pressure that the mineral olivine can form on the surface.

Comment: Edits cannot invalidate existing answers

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I've done it plenty of times before and nobody told me it was wrong. Should I make a new question every time I want to alter the question slightly?

Comment: I say it once more: edits shall not invalidate existing answers. Nor shall make the question too broad.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica it does not invalidate existing answers. It adds on to it by saying "if ice won't work, then what will?" Asking what element or compound has certain qualities does not make it too broad

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica you are wrong, i've done it before and things were fine. i've notified the answerers that i've updated the question a bit, and they will usually just ignore, or go "ok" and change their answer to fit the new slightly changed question. i don't even think there is a rule stating that edits can't invalidate answers. all i've seen is essentially "don't replace the question with a completely different question" which is just plain common sense.

Comment: @michaelgriffin we elected L.Dutch as moderator (note the diamond beside nir name) to enforce such rules. If you’ve done it before, please stop. Chickenpeep: yes, ask a new question.

Comment: For the record, the invalidation problem is reason bijillion on my list of reasons I wish ALL questions on WB were on hold for 10 minutes after being asked to allow time to get the question phrased right.

Comment: Can I delete this then?

Answer (score 2):

"frozen materials", however you put them, are solid.

Solid state is pretty unfavorable for life: diffusion is pretty slow in solid state, and to carry on all the chemistry related to life you need the right reactant at the right moment in the right place.

Only based on the above I would therefore state that no, no living thing can be based on frozen material. You need some sort of solution, and that requires a fluid state.

Comment: any such lifeform would have to be manufactured instead of grown and use some funky solid state nervous system and electromagnetically actuated servos. Basically it would be a robot built by its parents, and I can’t think of a natural way for such a thing to evolve...

Comment: I meant like only partly made of solid ice. Like we are made of both solid and liquid materials. This creature would still have blood and stuff.

Comment: damn solid life is impossible? dang. guess that invalidates the entirety of life on earth.

Comment: i'm just joking of course, but honestly i'd suggest changing it to "completely solid" instead of a "solid state"